# Using python, How to replace single quotes to double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I was giving input in double quotes, after processing some operations need to display output in double quotes where its giving in single quote format

**code:**

```
def movie_data(movie_list):
    mve = {}
    for k, v in movie_list.items():
        if type(v) == str:
            mve[k] = str(v) if v else None
        elif type(v) == dict:
            mve[k] = movie_data(v)
        else:
            pass
    return mve
movie_list = {"name":"Marvel","movies": {"spiderman":"Tom","Thor":"Chris"},"Review":"5star"}
movie_data(movie_list)
```

**Output:**

```
{'name': 'Marvel', 'movies': {'spiderman': 'Tom', 'Thor': 'Chris'}, 'Review': '5star'}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{"name":"Marvel","movies": {"spiderman":"Tom","Thor":"Chris"},"Review":"5star"}
```

Comment: The quotes aren't in the dictionary. That's just the way Python prints strings.

Comment: Single and double quotes are equivalent in Python, why does it matter which it uses when you print the dictionary?

Comment: If you're trying to create JSON, use the `json` module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18283909/9472529

Answer (score 4):

If you print a dictionary, it will use the dictionary method `__str__` to convert the dictionary to a printable string. The `__str__` method is the one using single quotes.

```
movie_list = {"name":"Marvel","movies": {"spiderman":"Tom","Thor":"Chris"},"Review":"5star"}
print(movie_list.__str__())
```

What you can do to get double quotes is to:

1. get the string that will get printed
2. replace the double quotes by single quotes

Here's the code to do it:

```
movie_list = {"name":"Marvel","movies": {"spiderman":"Tom","Thor":"Chris"},"Review":"5star"}
movie_list_str = movie_list.__str__().replace("'", '"')
print(movie_list_str)
```

And the output is:

```
{"name": "Marvel", "movies": {"spiderman": "Tom", "Thor": "Chris"}, "Review": "5star"}
```

Comment: This is super neat.  Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your motivation is, but the only time I want this is when I want my dictionary to be copy/pastable for JSON files.  It turns out the `json` module happens to do both in your case:

```
import json                                                                     
                                                                                
                                                                                
def movie_data(movie_list):                                                     
    mve = {}                                                                    
    for k, v in movie_list.items():                                             
        if type(v) == str:                                                      
            mve[k] = str(v) if v else None                                      
        elif type(v) == dict:                                                   
            mve[k] = movie_data(v)                                              
        else:                                                                   
            pass                                                                
    return mve                                                                  
                                                                                
                                                                                
movie_list = {                                                                  
    "name": "Marvel",                                                           
    "movies": {"spiderman": "Tom", "Thor": "Chris"},                            
    "Review": "5star",                                                          
}                                                                               
print(json.dumps(movie_data(movie_list)))                                       

# {"name": "Marvel", "movies": {"spiderman": "Tom", "Thor": "Chris"}, "Review": "5star"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `json` package.

```
import json
a = movie_data(movie_list)
print(json.dumps(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python uses single quotes or double quotes for strings : `"abc" == 'abc'`.

By default, `print` will display single quotes, unless the string already contains quotes :

```py
>>> "123"
'123'
>>> d = {'a': "b"}
>>> print(d)
{'a': 'b'}
>>> d
{'a': 'b'}
```

So those outputs are equal. The difference comes from Python's print function.

```py
>>> a = {'name': 'Marvel', 'movies': {'spiderman': 'Tom', 'Thor': 'Chris'}, 'Review': '5star'}
>>> b = {"name":"Marvel","movies": {"spiderman":"Tom","Thor":"Chris"},"Review":"5star"}
>>> a == b
True
```