# Python Append to List of Json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, append

In python I'm trying to create .json file like this:

```
dic = {"vendor": "test", "username": "", "password": "", "connection": {"type": "telnet"}}
```

The output is:

```
[
  {
    'vendor': 'test',
    'username': '',
    'password': '',
    'connection': {
      'type': 'telnet'
    }
  }
]
```

How can I force python to use `"` instead of `'`, for example I don't want this:

```
'vendor': 'test',
```

But this:

```
"vendor": "test",
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Python dictionary with double quotes as default quote format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283725/how-to-create-a-python-dictionary-with-double-quotes-as-default-quote-format)

Comment: Show us the code that creates the file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library you're using. Try using Python [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) built-in library:

```
import json 

dic = {"vendor": "test", "username": "", "password": "", "connection": {"type": "telnet"}}

out = json.dumps(dic)

out
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: the above code using json library...

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this

```
import json

dic = {"vendor": "test", "username": "", "password": "", "connection": {"type": "telnet"}}

print(json.dumps(dic))
```