# replace dictionary single quotes to double

Tags: python, json

```
dic = [{'one':1, 'two':'t', 'three': {'three.1': 3.1, 'three.2': '3.2' }}]
```

Desire Output,

```
[{"one":1, "two":"t", "three": {"three.1": 3.1, "three.2": "3.2" }}]
```

Tried Code:

```
ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(dic[0]))
```

here, Json converting the quotes but also changing the type to str. So I applied ast to change type. at end getting the same output with single quotes.

Output of Json.dumps:   `json.dumps(dic[0])`

```
'{"one": 1, "two": "t", "three": {"three.1": 3.1, "three.2": "3.2"}}'
```

Above pre and post single quotes are the issue.

Comment: Why do you need a specific type of quotes in the string representation of a `dict`?

Comment: Actually I need to upload these file to PowerBI, and need explode. PowerBI gives error with single quote.

Comment: @guy but it will chage the type to str

Comment: That sounds like what they really want is JSON.

Comment: If you create JSON file, there will be no single quotes around the JSON string. So use `json.dump()`

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283725/how-to-create-a-python-dictionary-with-double-quotes-as-default-quote-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats wrong with `json.dumps(dic)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the dictionary to terminal with double quotes, you can

```
>>> print(json.dumps(dic))
[{"one": 1, "two": "t", "three": {"three.1": 3.1, "three.2": "3.2"}}]
```